# Linking cpp using Clang for ARM on Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, arm, clang

I have downloaded the GNU Arm Embedded Toolchain (https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-rm/downloads), I downloaded the binary of LLVM, Win 32 bit (https://releases.llvm.org/download.html), and I am trying to compile a simple cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int count=0;
    count++;
    printf("Count %d", count);
    return count;
}
```

From the windows command prompt I tried to compile it with following:
**"C:\Program Files (x86)\LLVM\bin\clang++.exe" "C:\test\ProgramCpp\clang.cpp" -target armv7a-none-eabi "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\GNU Arm Embedded Toolchain\10 2020-q4-major\arm-none-eabi\include" "-LC:\Program Files (x86)\GNU Arm Embedded Toolchain\10 2020-q4-major\arm-none-eabi\lib\arm\v5te\hard" -fuse-ld=lld -v**

I got following errors:

```
ld.lld: error: unable to find library -lc++
ld.lld: error: unable to find library -lc++abi
ld.lld: error: unable to find library -lunwind
ld.lld: error: unable to find library -lclang_rt.builtins-armv7a
clang++: error: ld.lld command failed with exit code 1
```

On my main development mashine I got Visual Studio 2017.
On my other development mashine, where I do not have Visual Studio, I got msys2  with mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain, with gcc 10.2.0.
On booth mashines I got CMake3.19.2

1. What should I do to get the correct libraries that I can compile for ARM on Windows?
2. How should I compile the needed libraries for ARM in msys2?
3. Is there a possibility to compile clang that the Clang is not using Visual Studio since I got error on the mashine where no Visual Studio is: **clang++: warning: unable to find Visual Studio installation; try running Clang from a developer command prompt [-Wmsvc-not-found]**, maybe using GCC instead of Visual Studio?

Comment: It doesn't appear that compiling were the issue. The diagnostics provided refer to linker errors only.

Comment: I think that I might need the libraries for ARM? This is why I wrote that I have msys2 on my other dev mashine where I probably could make them, but how?

Comment: I was referring to the question title that's in disagreement with the question body. Either one should be fixed, presumably the title.

Comment: Does anyone know the answer where I could find, or how to build those missing libraries?